# JOIN three tables together and limit a row of thirst table - PDO

Tags: mysql, join, limit

I have three tables :

## table1

```
id          title                         name                    user                         token
1           supermarket                  big market              user1.example@gmail.com      aaaaa
2           hear styler                   stylist                user2.example@gmail.com      bbbbb
```

## table2

```
id          country               city                  user                          token
1           USA                 New York                user1.example@gmail.com       aaaaa
2           UK                   London                 user2.example@gmail.com       bbbbb
```

## table3

```
id                   url                        user                           token
1           uploadPic/image1.jpg       user1.example@gmail.com                 aaaaa
2           uploadPic/image2.jpg       user1.example@gmail.com                 aaaaa
3           uploadPic/image3.jpg       user2.example@gmail.com                 bbbbb
4           uploadPic/image4.jpg       user2.example@gmail.com                 bbbbb
5           uploadPic/image5.jpg       user2.example@gmail.com                 bbbbb
6           uploadPic/image6.jpg       user2.example@gmail.com                 bbbbb
```

and I used INNER JOIN to merge tables together:

```
$response['info'] = array();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table1` as tb1 
INNER JOIN `table2` as tb2 ON tb1.token = tb2.token 
INNER JOIN table3 as tb3 ON tb3.token = tb1.token
ORDER BY tb1.id DESC";
$run = $connect->prepare($sql);
$run->execute();
$record = $run->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$response['info'] = $recordAdvert;   
echo json_encode($response,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

and the result is :

```
{
    "info": [
        {
            "id": "6",
            "title": "superMarket",
            "name": "big market",
            "user": "user2.example@gmail.com",
            "token": "bbbbb",
            "country": "UK",
            "city": "London",
            "url": "uploadPic/image2.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "title": "superMarket",
            "name": "big market",
            "user": "user2.example@gmail.com",
            "token": "bbbbb",
            "country": "UK",
            "city": "London",
            "url": "uploadPic/image1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "title": "superMarket",
            "name": "big market",
            "user": "user2.example@gmail.com",
            "token": "bbbbb",
            "country": "UK",
            "city": "London",
            "url": "uploadPic/image6.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "title": "hear styler",
            "name": "stylist",
            "user": "user1.example@gmail.com",
            "token": "aaaaa",
            "country": "USA",
            "city": "NEW YORK",
            "url": "uploadPic/image5.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "hear styler",
            "name": "stylist",
            "user": "user1.example@gmail.com",
            "token": "aaaaa",
            "country": "USA",
            "city": "NEW YORK",
            "url": "uploadPic/image4.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "hear styler",
            "name": "stylist",
            "user": "user1.example@gmail.com",
            "token": "aaaaa",
            "country": "USA",
            "city": "NEW YORK",
            "url": "uploadPic/image3.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

but this is not that i want. there are must be just two rows because i have just two user and two token so i want to limit image to 1 but i can't due to when i used limit in image table to just limit image to one for both of users it limit total table.
the result must be something like this:

```
{
    "advert": [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "hear styler",
            "name": "stylist",
            "user": "user2.example@gmail.com",
            "token": "bbbbb",
            "country": "UK",
            "city": "London",
            "url": "uploadPic/image3.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "supermarket",
            "name": "big market",
            "user": "user1.example@gmail.com",
            "token": "aaaaa",
            "country": "USA",
            "city": "New york",
           "url": "uploadPic/image1.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

I edit the select query like this :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table1` as tb1 
INNER JOIN `table2` as tb2 ON tb1.token = tb2.token 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM table3 LIMIT 1) as tb3 ON tb3.token = tb1.token
ORDER BY tb1.id DESC";
```

but it limit the total row not just table 3 row.

```
{
    "info": [
        {
            "id": "6",
            "title": "superMarket",
            "name": "big market",
            "user": "user2.example@gmail.com",
            "token": "bbbbb",
            "country": "UK",
            "city": "London",
            "url": "uploadPic/image2.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why you select one of rows from table3 and skip all another? You must build some criteria which allows to determine what row from all possible ones must be returned.

Comment: in table 3 when i build criteria with limit 1 expression it's build just one json object and it's actually limit in total object not in image rows

Comment: LIMIT 1 is restriction, not criteria. Criteria may be, for example, "least `id` value in a group"...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery that use `LIMIT` to get just one URL per user.

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.title,
       t1.name,
       t1.user,
       t1.token,
       t1.country,
       t2.city,
       (SELECT t3.url
               FROM table3 t3
               WHERE t3.token = t1.token
               ORDER BY t3.id DESC
               LIMIT 1) url
       FROM table1 t1
            INNER JOIN table2 t2
                       ON t2.token = t1.token
       ORDER BY t1.id DESC;
```

Comment: thank you so much. something else if i want the number of pictures in table3 for each of users, how can i add it in select query?

Comment: @ShahramZarie: Add another subquery `(SELECT count(*) FROM table3 t3 WHERE t3.token = t1.token)`. If you have more questions about other figures, please open another question, as comments aren't meant to extended questions.